# Numbered messages arriving on server

Tags: java, c#

Encountered this question during an interview. What would be some optimal solutions for this problem?

Messages objects are sent out and arrive on a server. The messages are numbered from [ 0 , n ]. The messages arrive in a random manner.

Write a method that takes in a number and returns the list from [ 0, to number passed in ] if all messages from [ 0, to number passed in ] have arrived on the server. If all messages from [ 0, to number passed in ] have not arrived, return null.

Comment: Have you tried doing it? If so, what's not working? You can't expect people on SO to just answer your interview question/do your interview task

Comment: I have tried doing it. I was able to achieve log(n) time inserting and retrieving using an interval tree. This is a former interview question, not an ongoing task

Answer (score 0):

Sort the messages based on the number tagged and then take the length of the list. If the length is equal to the given number, then all messages have arrived.

For example, if I have an array of messages:

```
int[] messages = [0, 3, 2, 1, 8, 6, 5];

public void confirmArrival(int[] list, int number)
{
    // Implement the sort algorithm for list
    // ...

    if (list.length() == number + 1)
    {
        return list;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: No harm though, but this code formatting looks so cancerous. What is even the point of such a low quality answer?

Comment: Have a loot at my edit to see how code is proplery formatted.